# Mock a function call on a class you mocked

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

How do I mock

```
    with closing(StringIO()) as screenshot_stringio:
        screenshot.save(screenshot_stringio, format="PNG")
        screenshot_as_bytes = screenshot_stringio.getvalue()
```

assuming 'screenshot' is already Mocked.

I tried different permutations of:

```
    moduleiamtesting.classiamtesting.StringIO = Mock()
    moduleiamtesting.classiamtesting.StringIO.getvalue = Mock(return_value="test_bytes")
```

but cannot get it to work. the return value in my debugger is another mock

Comment: Can you please describe your problem as it is not clear from the given information

Answer (score 0):

One way to catch the get_value of `StringIO` is to patch the `sys.stdout` in the proper scope, not directly mocking the `StringIO` itself.

```
with mock.patch('sys.stdout', new=io.StringIO('xxx')) as fakeOutput:
   self.assertEqual('xxx', fakeOutput.getvalue().strip())
   # add your real test here, as no details provided
```